# Check if one date is between sets of dates in columns

Tags: excel-2010

I have table with 2 columns and 5 rows with a date in each cell. These 16 dates comprises 8 dates ranges. I want to check if a specific date is within any one of these 8 ranges of dates. How do I create a formula for this in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IF` function with the `AND` function:

```
=IF(AND(date1 <= mydate, mydate <= date2), TRUE, FALSE)
```

Here, `mydate` is the date you're looking at, and `date1` and `date2` are the dates to which you're comparing `mydate`.